# Скрипт для перезапуска приложения после его завершения на linux

Tags: bash, bat

У меня есть bat-файл на Windows, его содержание такое:

```
:label
java -jar app.jar
goto label
```

Как добиться того же на bash?

Comment: А тут не стоит заодно проверять, а не завершилось ли оно нормально (или наоборот, принудительно снято посылкой сигнала) и тогда цикл стоит прервать?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin с таким подходом вам лучше на erlang посмотреть.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как с помощью systemd сделать то же самое:

`/etc/systemd/system/my-java-app.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Java App

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

ExecStart=java -jar app.jar

User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Потом можно уже делать `systemctl enable my-java-app`, `systemctl start my-java-app`, `systemctl status my-java-app`

Comment: Тем, что системд как раз и запускает проги, следит за ними и перезапускает если надо. Плюс ещё можно сказать от чего зависит конкретная прога и чё с ней надо делать, если она повисла. Если она зависит от наличия сети и это сообщить через конфиг - служба не запустится, пока сеть не поднимется. Плюс удобно смотреть состояние запустила\упала, смотреть кусок журнала проги. В общем лучше почитать на википедии и во всяких вики типа https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(Русский) и https://habrahabr.ru/post/275645/

Comment: Здравствуй, root. Мне так тебя не хватало для перезапуска криво написанного бота на Java.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, из-за ошибок, получаемых от VK, процесс падать не должен, тем более, это виртуальный код.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, т.е. тебя не смутило, что это всего лишь пример и что ОП сам должен подставить свои значения?

Answer (score 4):

Аналог на **bash**

```
while true; do
  java -jar app.jar
done
```

Comment: @Peter, у вас в вопросе батник. Его эквивалент в Linux — сценарий для bash.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, сделайте это на Java, да и все. Наверняка, в Java можно создавать процессы и отслеживать, как они завершились. Циклы в Java, вероятно, тоже есть.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov это требует довольно специфичных знаний и довольно сложно.