# Как сделать, чтобы screen при краше восстанавливался?

Tags: ubuntu, vds, gnu-screen

Доброго времени суток! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы screen при краше восстанавливался?

Виртуальный хост. Система Ubuntu. Использую его для игровых серверов. 
При выполнение команды рестарта в игровой консоли screen закрывается и получается, что сервер не перезагружается, а просто отключается.

Что я запускал в скрине:

```html
#!/bin/sh
clear
while :
do
```

На сколько я понимаю - это и есть то о чем вы мне говорите.

```html
#!/bin/sh
clear
while :
do
echo "Starting rust...\n"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/servera/rustexperimental:/home/servera/rustexperimental/RustDedicated:{$LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ;
exec ./RustDedicated -batchmode -nographics \
-server.ip 212.76.133.91 \
-server.port 28015 \
-rcon.ip 212.76.133.91 \
-rcon.port 28006 \
-rcon.password "" \
-server.maxplayers 50 \
-server.hostname "PSS 86 rus by.Bludnik [TP|HOME|KITS|CLANS|Ресуры-X2]" \
-server.identity "myserver" \
-server.level "Procedural Map" \
-server.seed 6 \
-server.worldsize 2800 \
-server.saveinterval 350 \
-server.globalchat true \
-logfile "logfilename.log" \
-server.description "[TP|HOME|KITS|CLANS|Ресуры-X2]" \
-server.headerimage "http://oxidemod.org/styles/oxide/logo.png" \
-server.url ""
echo "\nRestarting rust...\n"
sleep 10
done
```

Может тут что-то не так?

Comment: А как запускаете и какой конкретно игровой сервер? Что-то я подозреваю, что это просто так не исправить

Comment: например, используйте бесконечный цикл: вместо `ваша-программа её-аргументы` запускайте `while :; do ваша-программа её-аргументы; done`

Comment: screen -m -A -d -S rust ./start.sh

Comment: Название скрина и есть название игры Rust Experimental

Comment: связанный вопрос [Скрипт для перезапуска приложения после его завершения на linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/657255/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -d -m /opt/games/bin/run-all
```

Два указанных ключа делают именно то, что вы хотите.

В самом скрипте вы можете выполнить любые команды по запуску чего угодно. Если в нём потребуется дополнить переменные окружения до стандартного набора, то делайте так:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Можно более подробно, что и куда.

Comment: `crontab -e` вставить сохранить

Answer (score 0):

предполагаю, что вы запускаете вашу программу примерно так:

```
$ screen опции-screen-а ваша-программа её-опции-и-параметры
```

насколько я понял, вам требуется, чтобы ваша программа запускалась (после завершения её работы) вновь и вновь.

для этого можно поместить её запуск в бесконечный цикл, используя команду `while` оболочки, примерно так:

```
$ screen опции-screen-а sh -c "while :; do ваша-программа её-опции-и-параметры; done"
```

Comment: Встречал ваши комментарии, alexander barakin
Как-то, что-то ставил менял. $ screen bash -c 'while :; date; sleep 2; done' и все безуспешно. (Я чайник в этих делах)

Comment: смотрите внимательнее: вы `do` пропустили. синтаксис команды `while` (можно посмотреть командой `$ help while`): `while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done`. вместо первого набора команд вам достаточно команды `:` (она же `true`)

Comment: Где именно? 
Можно маленько, как для чайника. XD

Comment: просто скопируйте, вставьте, и впишите ваши команды. никаких «специальных» знаний для этого вообще не требуется. нужна лишь внимательность.