# Восстановление работы скрипта

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

Есть запущенный скрипт на python3.
Время от времени (из-за особенностей API Telegram) падает.
Каким образом можно отладить его автоматическое восстановление работы? Краем уха слышал, что в этом помогают демоны, но хотелось бы какой-то конкретики.
За ответ сойдет и какой-либо гайдик, ибо, судя по всему, мои запросы в гугл формируются не совсем правильно для решения данного вопроса)
Спасибо!

Comment: Если это особенности API Telegram, то почему бы не отлавливать ошибки в самом скрипте?

Comment: systemd, supervisord, etc могут автоматически перезапускать задачи.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416