# Автозапуск скрипта Debian

Tags: linux, debian, автозапуск

Необходимо включать скрипт после включения сервера.
Добавил в файл `/etc/rc.local` строку `screen -d -m -S MyScript /home/script.sh`

Но скрипт включается и завершается с ошибкой, потому что он подключается к MongoDB серверу (локальному), а MongoDB сервер еще не успел включиться.

Вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт `screen -d -m -S MyScript /home/script.sh` включался после того, как будет запущена MongoDB?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416

Answer (score 0):

```
sleep 50 && screen -d -m -S MyScript /home/script.sh
```

В вашем случае, выполнение команды `screen -d -m -S MyScript /home/script.sh` произойдёт через 50 секунд. Можете указать своё время (дефолтное значение - в секундах), необходимое для того, чтобы подождать пока будет запущена MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "screen -d -m -S MyScript /home/script.sh" |at now + 2 minutes`

Это если по-простому. В таком виде `rc.local` не будет висеть и ждать 50 секунд, как в примере со `sleep`.

А вообще-то, если совсем правильно, то надо бы написать юнит для systemd с зависимостью от MongoDB.