# Проблема с работой со screen через php ssh2

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh

Делаю небольшой скрипт для автоматического включения игрового сервера. Присоединяюсь к самому серверу через библиотеку ssh2 в php 7.4. Соединение происходит успешно, но вот беда, подобным способом нельзя зайти в окно screen, чтобы включить сервер через SH файл. Пробовал через 'screen -r GAME -X "sh start.sh"', но всё равно никакого эффекта.
Можно ли каким либо образом зайти в окно screen через php ssh2 или сделать какой-нибудь костыль, чтобы после отсоединения от сервера сам игровой сервер не выключался?

Comment: Зачем вам вообще screen? Почему бы не выполнять запуск через какую-нибудь систему, которая специально предназначена для запуска служб?

Comment: Можете привести пример такой службы?

Comment: systemd, supervisor, pm2

Comment: А можете привести пример включения сервера через одну из этих служб через файл start.sh, просто я в этом не силён.

Comment: Примеры есть в документациях соответствующих проектов

Comment: Попробовал я запускать сервер через систему Systemd, но тут есть одна загвоздка, сам сервер никогда не остановит свой вывод, из-за чего Systemd никогда не передаст управление командной строке, из-за чего при отсоединении от сервера сам игровой сервер тоже выключается. Есть ли какая нибудь настройка, чтобы Systemd не ждал конца?

Comment: Вы что-то напутали, systemd ничего нигде не ждёт и на отсоединения никак не реагирует

Comment: Пример вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416