# Запуск программы в bash

Tags: bash

программа написана под винду на asp.net, и адаптирована под ОС Убунту. Хочу создать systemd  unit для автоматического запуска программы при перезагрузке/включения ПК. Сама программа запускается через терминал командой dotnet -name file. Подскажите плиз пример скрипта на баше для запуска

Comment: Если вы хотите создать systemd unit, то зачем вам скрипт на баше? Пихайте этот dotnet прямо в юнит да и всё

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416