# Запуск .sh (screen) скрипта через crontab

Tags: ubuntu, sh, crontab, gnu-screen

*Здравствуйте, почему-то не нашёл ничего, что решало бы мою проблему*

У меня есть игровой сервер `(srcds)`, он запускается через отдельный скрипт `.sh`

Я использую **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** на VDS

Скрипт выглядит вот так:

```
screen ./srcds_run -параметр запуска 1 -параметр запуска 2 и т.д.
```

Запускаю я его, логично, через терминал

```
cd /home/user/steamcmd/game && ./run.sh
```

Игровой сервер запускается и начинает работать

Я хочу, чтобы в случае перезагрузки сервера скрипт запускался сам. Естественно мне с этим должен помочь `crontab`.

```
$ crontab -e
```

В планировщик я ставлю задание:

```
@reboot cd /home/user/steamcmd/game && ./run.sh >>/home/user/cronlogs/run.log
```

Но это почему-то не работает и в логе появляется сообщение об ошибке: `Must be connected to a terminal.`

---

**Что мне нужно делать чтобы .sh скрипт со screen запускался автоматически, после перезагрузки?**

Comment: Может лучше так, не? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я НАШЁЛ РЕШЕНИЕ!
Мне помог ответ [отсюда](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383046/unable-to-run-code-in-screen)

я исправил свой `.sh` скрипт, добавив туда `-d -m`

В итоге скрипт стал выглядеть вот так:

```
screen -d -m ./srcds_run -параметр запуска 1 -параметр запуска 2 и т.д.
```

Теперь при запуске у меня не открывается автоматически консоль, а для подключения к ней мне нужно использовать `screen -r`

После добавления `-d -m` скрипт стал запускаться автоматически, после перезагрузки

*p.s. трое суток потратил на поиск решения и как только задал вопрос, сразу нашёл ответ*