# Останавливается выполнение фоновой программы на сервере Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Создал небольшого бота. Арендовал самый дешевый сервер:
Операционная Система Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (ENG)
Конфигурация 1x2.2ГГц, 1Гб RAM, 1IP
Диск 20Гб HDD RAID (Операционная система)
Запускаю бота:
python3 bot.ry&
он корректно отрабатывает совершенно не сложную логику
но почему-то в течении суток или около того программа останавливается,
при этом судя по uptime системы она не перезагружалась.
Вопросы:
Можно ли сделать процесс неубиваемым?
Как проследить что происходит с процессом (как и от чего он выключается)?
Можно ли автоматически возобновлять процесс?

Comment: Ну для начала запускать его через нормальный менеджер фоновых служб вроде systemd или supervisor, а не костылём в интерактивном сеансе

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416